# Html video player suggestions

Tags: html, html5-video, media-player, vast

I'm looking for Html video player that has the ability to add advertising clip or image at the begining of the video like what YouTube does.

What video player do you recommend?

Thanks

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-responsive-video-player-advertising-/4282278

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would like to recommend Video.js: HTML5 Video Player

Comment: I don't think it support advertising ,Does it?

Comment: Yes. It does. You just need a plug-in called "videojs-ads".  This plug-in lets you add common functionality needed by video advertisement libraries working with Video.js.

Comment: You need to use player that supports `VAST` or `VPAID`